# Como agregar boton eliminar en las opciones de un componente select

Tags: html, angularjs

Buen dia.

Tengo el siguiente componente select multiple

```
<select multiple ng-model="templateSelect" id="sel_templates" material-select watch ng-change="loadWeeklyConfiguration(templateSelect)">
    <option  ng-repeat="x in templates" value="{{x.id}}" data-icon="delete_outline">
        {{x.title}}
    </option>
</select>
```

¿Como podria lograr con dicho componente lo siguiente?

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Los botes ejecutarian la accion de eliminar el item correspondiente.

De antemano gracias

Comment: Existe una librería excelente para implementar tablas, busquedas globales y de paso insertar botones como el que necesitas sin mucho trabajo... te dejo el link http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

Answer (score 0):

podrias agregar botones que llamen a una funcion, pasandole el id del item

```
    <select multiple ng-model="templateSelect" id="sel_templates" material-select watch ng-change="loadWeeklyConfiguration(templateSelect)">
       <option  ng-repeat="x in templates" value="{{x.id}}" data-icon="delete_outline">
         {{x.title}}
         <button (click)="eliminar(x.id)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
         </button>
       </option>
    </select>
```

y en tu archivo.ts unicamente colocarias la funcion eliminar(id)